# machine code template for immediate addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

what is the machine code language for immediate addressing..

if the machine code template for register adddressing is

OPCODE(6 bits) D(1 bit) W(1 bit) MOD(2bits) REG(3bits) R/M(3bits)

total 16 bits.

m using intel 80386 intel microprocessor!

Comment: You really don't have right tags for this question at all.  Perhaps you should look over the existing tags and edit the tags you've put on this question.  There's a button labeled "Tags" that can help you pick a better set of tags.

Comment: really dont know what tag to use.. what tag is there for asking questions related to microprocessors?

Comment: perhaps assembly as a tag? not sure how visual applies

Comment: "what tag is there for asking questions related to microprocessors?"  Please look at the top of the page.  See the word "Tags"?  Click it.  Read the tags.  Think.  Find tags that relate to your question.  Update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes to the format for immediate operands. Usually (possibly always) the high bit of the opcode is 1 for instructions with immediate operands. The D bit is replaced with an X (extension) bit. If the operands are 8-bit (W=0), then the X bit is ignored. If the operands are not 8-bit and X=0, then the immediate value is the same size as the operand size. If X=1, then the immediate is an 8-bit number which is sign-extended to the current operand size. Next, the REG field is replaced with an opcode extension, which will be different depending on the instruction in use. Finally, the immediate value is added to the end of the instruction, in little endian.

For more information see http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/lecture.html, specifically sections 21 and 37.